# What is the difference between an Array[x] object and [Object,Object,Object] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wrote a code that loops through an array to look for a match

```
function getCategoryImage(category) {
    console.log(categoriesCovers);
    var categorySent = category.toLowerCase();
    var categoryCompare;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCoverLength; i++) {
        categoryCompare = categoriesCovers[i].category.toLowerCase();
        if (categoryCompare == categorySent) {
            return categoriesCovers[i].image;
        }
    }
}
```

However it sometimes return the correct strings and sometimes undefined. (it behaves differently on consecutive page loads)

When it returns undefined the console outputs the array in question as:
Array[5] (with the correct objects inside)

When it works correctly it outputs:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] (with the same objects inside)

What is the difference between the two? I think this will lead me to the error fix.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(categoriesCovers)` instead of `console.log(categoriesCovers);` and see what that outputs instead?

Comment: As you said, one is an array with five `undefined` values and the other is an array with five objects. There is nothing special about that. You should have a look at the code that constructs `categoriesCovers` to find the issue.

Comment: well if it does not find anything, you do not return anything so it will be undefined.

Comment: And how are you calling the code above? I have a feeling it is related to how you are executing code in the console.

Comment: @adilapapaya in that case it outputs [] when it fails. So what I'm guessing is that it is not outputting it as a JSON object when it fails right?

Comment: @Cruclax, it looks like your `categoriesCovers` has not been populated yet when you make the call. So, make sure that you've initialized it first before calling `getCategoryImage`. You can also insert a check along the lines of `if(categoriesCovers && categoriesCovers.length){ /* then only do stuff */ }` either to decide if you should call `getCategoryImage` or within `getCategoryImage` itself (to decide if you should continue).